# OnTriggerExit Is Being Unreliable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a simple script for controlling a character, where a **trigger box collider with rigidbody** detects if the character is on the ground (based on collision with objects of layer "Ground").

OnTriggerEnter seems to fire all the time, yet sometimes the OnTriggerExit doesn't fire - not all the time, only sometimes. Does anyone know what the issue is? To my knowledge this should be a guaranteed thing.

```
// Script On The Trigger Object (attached to parent Player Object)
// OnTriggerExit Log not firing (because function not firing) only sometimes, 
// but this will then sometimes result in infinite jumps
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"))
    {
        Debug.Log("On Ground!");
        NotifyGrounded(true);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Leaving Ground");
        NotifyGrounded(false);
    }
}
```

And (though I think this is probably not relevant)

```
// This is the code attached to the Player Object
bool jumpReady = true;
bool grounded = false;
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    OtherMovementStuff();
    HandleJump();
}

protected void HandleJump()
{
    if (jumpReady && grounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        jumpReady = false;

        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        Invoke(nameof(ReadyJump), jumpCooldown);
    }
}
```

Comment: usually the triggers/collissions dont work when either the conditions to do so arent met  or you dont use physics to move

Comment: All my movement consists of either adding forces, or setting velocity so they *should* work with triggers and collisions. It's really strange because it *sometimes* works